# In an underdetermined linear regression setup, why does the residual sum of squares equal 0?

Tags: regression

In an underdetermined linear regression where the parameters to estimate outnumber the observations, why is it the case the residual sum of squares, defined as:

$$
RSS = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\widehat{y}_i)^2
$$

equal zero?

Comment: one way to look at it: if you have at least as many $\beta_p$ as $y_i$, through a change of basis you can make it so that each $x_i$ has zeros in all entries except the $i$th one such that each $y_i$ can have its own regression coefficient.

Comment: @JohnMadden What about the situation I describe in my answer? // If you believe the situation I describe is contained in your approach, please do post as an answer. While I do not believe your approach to be 100% correct (because of something annoying like I describe in my answer), I had never thought about it that for for the case where an over-parameterized regression can get perfect (in-sample) predictions.

Comment: @Dave I didn't mention the case with duplicate X's because you did :) you're right, in that case there's no way to rewrite the x's as I describe: rather, we can think of those two observations as sharing a regression coefficient.

Comment: In geometry one used to talk about *points in general position*

Comment: *"In an underdetermined linear regression setup, why does the residual sum of squares equal 0?"* The question is based in a false premise.

Comment: The simplest (non-trivial) example I can imagine of this circumstance is revealing: measure $y$ for two subjects having the same value of $x$ and fit an ordinary least squares model $E[y]=\alpha+\beta x$ (the number of parameters, two, equals or exceeds the number of observations).  Consider what happens when the measurements differ. Another interesting example fits the model $E[y]=\alpha + \beta$ to the same data. Even when the $x$ values *differ* the RSS can be nonzero.

Answer (score 6):

That need not be the case.

It is routine to say that a polynomial of degree greater than the sample size will give a perfect fit to the data. However, this will not be the case if two points have equal feature ($X$) values but unequal outcome ($y$) values. No function can accommodate that. At least one of those points will have a fitted value $\hat y_i$ not equal to its observed $y_i$ value, thus a strictly positive squared residual.

**EDIT**

For example...

```
X  Y
1  1
2  2
3  3
3  4
4  5
5  6
```

No matter what a model predicts for `x = 3`, that model will make a prediction that is incorrect, resulting in a positive sum of squared residuals.

This really has nothing to do with $p>n$. If you have two instances with equal feature values and unequal outcomes, the model cannot ever get both right.

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6  y
0  0  0  0  0  0  1.1
0  0  1  1  1  0  0.8
0  0  0  0  1  1  0.3
0  1  0  1  0  0  1.1
0  1  0  1  0  0  0.5
```

The final two rows have identical feature values yet different outcomes, so a model will get at least one of those wrong, leading to a positive sum of squared residuals.

Comment: Your new example doesn't satisfy $n < p$?

Answer (score 4):

With one predictor (and an intercept): two points determines a lines exactly, with less than two points there are infinitely many lines that pass through that point ...

With two predictors (and an intercept): three points determines a plane exactly, with less than three points infinitely many planes will fit perfectly ...

The same principle continues into higher dimension.

Comment: (some exceptions as noted in the answer by @Dave)

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}$
Suppose all observations of explanatory variables are identical, then it can be shown that
\begin{align}
RSS = \sum_{i = 1}^n(y_i - \bar{y})^2. \tag{1}
\end{align}
Hence $RSS > 0$ unless $y_1, \ldots, y_n$ are all identical.

The reason of this example cannot provide a perfect fit is that the rank of the design matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ is $1$. Following this key observation, there are actually countless examples of $RSS > 0$ as long as $\rank(X) < n$ (unless $y$ is a multiple of $e = 1_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$). This is clear from the projection point of view of least squares, because $\|P_{\text{col}(X)}y\| < \|y\|$ under the condition $\rank(X) < n$ and the linear algebra fact $\dim(\text{col}(X)) = \rank(X) < n$ (there is a theorem in linear algebra states that the rank of a matrix is equal to the dimension of column space).

The conjecture will be true if $\operatorname{rank}(X) = n$, i.e., $X$ is of full row rank. In this case, the dimension of column space is $n$ too, which implies that the columns of $X$ spans the whole space $\mathbb{R}^n$, hence $y$ can be perfectly expressed as a linear combination of columns of $X$ (i.e., $y = P_{\text{col}(X)}y$), this gives $RSS = \|y - P_{\text{col}(X)}y\|^2 = 0$.

---

*Proof of $(1)$.* Suppose there are $n$ observations $(y_i, x_{i1}, \ldots, x_{ip}) \equiv (y_i, x_1, \ldots, x_p)$, $i = 1, \ldots, n$. Then the least squares minimizes the objective function
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 1}^n (y_i - (\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \cdots + \beta_p x_p))^2. \tag{2}
\end{align}
Set $t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \cdots + \beta_px_p$, then it is easy to see the $t$ minimizes $(2)$ is $t^* = \bar{y}$.  This implies that the minimizer $(\hat{\beta}_0, \ldots, \hat{\beta}_p)$ must satisfy $\hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 x_1 + \cdots + \hat{\beta}_px_p = \bar{y}$, which is equivalent to $\hat{y}_i = \bar{y}$.  This leads to $RSS = \sum_{i = 1}^n (y_i - \bar{y})^2$.

Comment: I don’t agree about me having defined the sum to involve subtracting $\bar y$. Could you please explain your rationale?

Comment: @Dave It can be proved, if the rows of $X$ are identical, the RSS is like this. I will add a proof later (basically all $\hat{y}_i = \bar{y}$).

Comment: What is the relationship to what I wrote?

Comment: You didn't write.  I kind of dug a little deeper to your example.

Comment: @Dave Proof added, is it clear now?

Comment: Sorry, I may have misread your example, I will remove the citation to your answer then.